# MySQLoptimization in combining 3 tables and search

Tags: mysql

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with this MySQL query ?

```
select distinct(a.productId)
  from product a
  left join product_keyword b
    on b.productId = a.productId
  left join keywords c
    on c.keywordId = b.keywordId
  where a.productName LIKE '%truck%' OR c.value LIKE '%truck%'
  limit 100;
```

Actually I need to join 3 tables (`product`, `product_keyword` and `keywords`) and search based on user input. One product can be multiple keywords and I store it (`keywordId` from `table` keywords in `product_keyword`).

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: The syntax is fine, so you'll need to supply *just* a little more detail to explain WHAT is wrong.....

Comment: i tried to run but my sql will hang everytime i try it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `%` wildcard in the prefix of a LIKE search, MySQL isn't able to utilize any indexes for the search. Instead, MySQL must scan all of the rows.

You should at least have indexes on the join columns (productID and keywordID) so that MySQL is able to more quickly perform the join operations. However, if the result set is too large, MySQL will perform a scan for the JOINs as well.

Most likely, MySQL is scanning each row in product, then performing the JOIN to product_keyword, then performing the join to keywords. Then, it checks to see if it can exclude the row based on the WHERE clause. Once it returns 100 rows, it stops.

Answer (score 0):

If your tables are large, this will be a very expensive query. Using a leading wildcard on a LIKE query will usually be very slow. If you need that sort of search capability, it is probably better to do it externally in Lucene or something similar, rather than in the database.